# Write a very basic copy from one file into another using command line arguments

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to make a basic copy one file into another file program.
My code right now is

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) !=3:
    print 'usage: filecopy source destination'
else:
    try:
        infile = open(sys.argv[1])
        outfile = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

    except IOError:
        print 'source file does not exist'


    getline(infile, line)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

As you can hopefully see I am trying to output why the program won't work if the user tries to use it wrong.

I recently wrote a c++ program doing the same thing as this, and it worked just fine, but now I have to transfer the same logic into a different syntax.

Comment: just saw my else is indented too much fixed it.

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: right now it is saying that there is an invalid syntax with the () in "elif infile.fail()"

Comment: What is this `getline` function you are calling?

Comment: I'm not sure if getline is a function in python or not, like I said I am used to C++ so I am trying to write a line of infile into the string line and then write that into an output file.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to write a line of infile into the string line and then
>   write that into an output file.

Don't try to "write C++" in Python. For the task at hand:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) !=3:
    print('usage: filecopy source destination')
else:
    try:
        with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as inf, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as outf:
            for line in inf:
               outf.write(line)
    except IOError:
        print('{} does not exist or cannot be read'.format(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: What about use 'out.write(inf.read())'  instead of for cycle?

Comment: Will also work, but given the original requirement _"into the string line and then write that into an output file"_ I wanted to show how to do that specifically in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Remove unwanted spaces from your code. It might work.

I already edited you post, please try to run this code.

You have to handle `try...except` if file not exist.

```
import shutil
import sys
if len(sys.argv) !=3:
    print 'usage: filecopy source destination'
else:
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    except IOError:
        print 'source file does not exist'
```

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filecopy.py", line 2, in <module>
    infile = open(sys.argv[1])
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined"

that's the error I am getting now.

Comment: imported `sys` module.

Comment: alright fixed that. Now it is saying that infile = open(sys.argv[1]) is out of range.

Comment: moved if condition before try.

Comment: actually nevermind :( it says name outfile is not defined in outfile.close()

Comment: You have to open `outfile` as `w` write mode. Also give arguments you passed in console.

Comment: alright did that now getline is not defined :/. The arguments I am passing in are python filecopy.py filecopy.cpp(a file I wrote earlier) out.txt so trying to copy filecopy.cpp into out.txt.

Comment: use `shutil` if you want to copy only.

Comment: so replace getline with shutil?

Comment: I dont know anything about `getline` if you have user define function then use it. Otherwise use `shutil`

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv

def main () :

        sourcefile = argv [ 1 ]
        destfile = argv [ 2 ]

        sourceptr = open ( sourcefile , 'r')

        destptr = open ( destfile , 'w')

        destptr . write ( sourceptr . read ()  )

        sourceptr . close ()

        destptr . close ()

main ()
```